How to make a SDP problem solve faster in Matlab?
we are now using the cvx toolbox in matlab to solve a sdp problem, like following:
    cvx_begin sdp quiet
    variable V(257, 257) hermitian
    maximize(real(trace(R * V)));
    subject to
        diag(V) == 1;
        V >= 0;
    cvx_end

we have tried admm, but the time cost is even more, we are now trying to use the BCD solution to do the problem, but we don't know how to change to presentation of the problem.
